# MarkLogic Corb SEVERE: received more than 1 results: 1

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-corb

I have a MarkLogic CoRB job. It should returns 100 records. But it fails for `SEVERE: received more than 1 results: 1`.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

uris.xqy:

```
declare namespace lab = "http://labs.com/record";
declare namespace meta="http://labs.com/lab/record/meta";
let $org := ("Ros* Lab*")
for $uri in cts:uris(
                     (),
                     (),
               cts:and-query((
                  cts:collection-query('/Lab'),
                  cts:field-range-query("updated","<","2023-08-18"),
                  cts:or-query((
                      cts:field-word-query("do",$org,"case-insensitive"),
                ))
            ))
        )
 return (count($uri),$uri)
```

uris-process.xqy:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace lab = "http://labs.com/record";
declare namespace meta="http://labs.com/lab/record/meta";
declare variable $URI as xs:string external;
xdmp:set-request-time-limit(3600),

for $uris in $URI
let $doc := fn:doc($uris)
let $meta := <lab:Record><meta:Metadata>

                 $doc//meta:IDNumber}
                 {$doc//meta:ReportDate}
                 {$doc//meta:ReportNumbers}
             </meta:Metadata></lab:Record>

 let $IDNumber := fn:data($meta//meta:IDNumber)

return
xdmp:save(fn:concat("/XML/",$IDNumber,".xml")$IDNumber ,$meta)
```

Produces this exception:

```
SEVERE: interrupted: exiting
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2088)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
        at java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService.poll(ExecutorCompletionService.java:202)
        at com.marklogic.developer.corb.Monitor.monitorResults(Monitor.java:97)
        at com.marklogic.developer.corb.Monitor.run(Monitor.java:76)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Sep 11, 2023 3:32:41 PM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager run
SEVERE: received more than 1 results: 1
Sep 11, 2023 3:32:41 PM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager stop
INFO: cleaning up
Sep 11, 2023 3:32:41 PM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager main
SEVERE: Error while running CORB
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: received more than 1 results: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URIs module doesn't look right.

You are iterating over each URI with a for loop.

```
for $uri in cts:uris(
```

and then for each of those URIs you are returning a count (of one) and then the `$uri`, for each of the 100 URIs.

So, the first thing returned in your job is the count of `1`, but then you are returning 199 other items in the sequence.

You want to instead let a `$uris` variable

```
let $uris := cts:uris(
```

and then return only one sequence that has the count and then each of the $uris.

```
return (count($uris), $uris)
```